# A question about the Dendriform algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, nonassociative-algebras

Dendriform algebra is a well-known non-associative algebra defined by Loday and Ronco. More precisely,

A  **Dendriform algebra**  is a $k$-module $D$ together with two binary operations $\{\prec, \succ\}$, such that,
\begin{align}
(x\prec y) \prec z=\ & x \prec (y\prec z)
+x\prec (y \succ z),  \\
%
(x\succ y)\prec z=\ & x\succ (y\prec z),\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \ \ \ \  \\
%
 x\succ(y \succ z)=\ & (x\prec y)\succ z
 +(x\succ y) \succ z，
\end{align}
for $x, y, z\in D$.
By the second identity, it looks not symmetric, can we add
$(x\prec y)\succ z=\  x\prec (y\succ z)$? Or under some condition, commutative? can we get $(x\prec y)\succ z=\  x\prec (y\succ z)$?

Comment: Interesting idea. I don't immediately see a good example of a dendriform algebra that satisfies your extra relation; my go-to example (the quasisymmetric functions) certainly does not.

Comment: @darij grinberg,thank you for your effort.

Comment: Well, a trivial example is an associative algebra $(A,+,\cdot)$ with $\prec:=\cdot$ and $x\succ y:=0$.